# JavaFX format double in TableColumn

Tags: java, javafx, formatting, tableview

```
TableColumn<Product, Double> priceCol = new TableColumn<Product,Double>("Price");
priceCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Double>("price"));
```

How do I format the doubles in this column to have 2 decimal places(Because they are the column for price)?By default they only show 1 decimal place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a cell factory that generates cells that use a currency formatter to format the text that is displayed. This means the price will be formatted as a currency in the current locale (i.e. using the local currency symbol and appropriate rules for number of decimal places, etc.).

```
NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
priceCol.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<Product, Double>() {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Double price, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(price, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText(currencyFormat.format(price));
        }
    }
});
```

Note this is *in addition to* the `cellValueFactory` you are already using. The `cellValueFactory` determines the value that is displayed in a cell; the `cellFactory` determines the cell that defines *how* to display it.

Comment: worked for me as well and I was able to edit it to work with Decimal Formats too.

Comment: I tried the same solution into my project . But I am getting "Cannot format given Object as a Number". I am passing double value.