# Javafx double variable with two decimal places

Tags: java, double, precision, decimalformat

I have a variable name "unitPrice" which is double.
if the value of unitprice = 12.23;
it is ok and giving double precision with two decimal place.

However if the value is unitPrice = 12.50; or unitPrice = 12.00;

it is giving "12.5" and "12.0" 
is there any way to make this "12.50" and "12.00" ?

here is my code for that.

```
unitPrice = 12.00;
        DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".##");

    double formatDecimal = new Double(df2.format(unitPrice)).doubleValue();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A `double` variable does not store the precision that you specify with `DecimalFormat`. The `DecimalFormat` object is used to convert a number into a `String` in the format that you specify (because you called `format()`).

Therefore, `df2.format(unitPrice)` will evaluate into a `String` of value `"12.00"`. `new Double("12.00")` will create a `Double` with a value of `12d`, and `doubleValue()` will simply return primitive `double` value `12d`.

Furthermore, using `.##` means that the value will be rounded off to 2 decimal places, but if you have a value with less than 2 decimal places, it will not be made 2 decimal places.

Formatting is used when you need a number to be presented as a `String`.

```
double price = 12;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.println(price);
System.out.println(df.format(price));
```

Output:

```
12
12.00
```

#### Edit

Assuming you are using JavaFX (because your question originally had `javafx` tag).

One way is to use `setCellFactory()` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48733121/javafx-format-double-in-tablecolumn?rq=1)).

Another way is to use `setCellValueFactory()`.

```
@FXML private TableColumn<Foo, String> column;

column.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Foo, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

            @Override
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Foo, String> param) {
                return Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
                           return df.format(param.getValue().getPrice());
                       }, param.getValue().priceProperty());
            }
        })
```

;

Comment: So, then is there any way to keep it in numeric value rather then String to have trailing zeroes? Because, I use this value in table column and I don't want to keep playing with the value. All I want is actually store the price value with double precision(including trailing zeroes) and store it in table column in numeric format.