# display two decimal places of a float in a TableView JavaFx

Tags: javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

So basically I'm developing this Javafx app following the DAO pattern...
and I want the floats to have that .00 end instead of .0 (to represents the balance.. money ) 
[balance records in tableview with .0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/punEq.png)

here's how I initialized the tableview components

```java
idC.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().idProperty().asObject());
balanceC.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().balanceProperty().asObject());
dateC.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().dateProperty());
timeC.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().timeProperty());
```

Comment: I believe your question has already been asked and answered. [TableView column data set to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917983/tableview-column-data-set-to-2-decimal-places) and also [JavaFX format double in TableColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48733121/javafx-format-double-in-tablecolumn). You are expected to search for answers before posting a question. I recommend you read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Abra I read them but they didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `cellFactory` *in addition to* your `cellValueFactory` (I'm assuming `balanceC` is a `TableColumn<T, Double>` for some type `T`:

```
balanceC.setCellFactory(c -> new TableCell<>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Double balance, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(balance, empty);
        if (balance == null || empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText(String.format("%.2f", balance.doubleValue());
        }
    }
});
```

You can add currency symbols and use more sophisticated formatting if needed.

Answer (score -1):

CellFactory isn't needed if you don't want to add more unnecessary code.

First, change your `TableColumn<XXX,Double> balanceC` to `TableColumn<XXX,String> balanceC`

Then change your cell value factory to:

```
balanceC.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().balanceProperty().asString("%.2f"));
```

Easy and cleaner way IMO.

Personally, I write custom CellFactory when I need more complex cells, for example: mixing images and other nodes inside the cell.

Comment: definitely wrong - a column should represent a property of the item, a cell is responsible for the visual representation of that property

Comment: @kleopatra I understand you , but javadoc of TableColumn Says:
```Type parameters:
<S> – The type of the TableView generic type (i.e. S == TableView<S>)
<T> – The type of the content in all cells in this TableColumn.```

So the type T does not have to be related to the item. The accepted answer really work with string also (setText(String.format("%.2f", balance.doubleValue());)

Comment: @kleopatra you said `a cell is responsible for the visual representation of that property.` But the visual representation of that property, in the accepted answer,  is String. What's the problem then? (accepted answer is doing 'setText('string')).

Comment: the problem is that this answer does it in the wrong place

Comment: what is the right place? I am here to learn and improve my skills, I just want to help others... sorry if I'm breaking some rules...

Comment: you are not breaking rules, you are just doing it the wrong way :)